# Footer div, it does not behave as wanted

Tags: javascript, html, css, internal

I have a problem.
Screenprinter of webpage and code is attached.

PROBLEM:
The footer div will not vertical align 100% at the bottom of the page. As you see on image there is some space between the footer div (in red) and the bottom of the page. You also see the yellow main body div under neath the red footer div (the red footer div should cover the yellow in bottom. What can i do to achieve that the vertical align of the red footer completly at the bottom?

[iMAGE OF WEBPAGE,CODING IN THE STYLE-TAG AND THE MAIN BODY OF THE "HTML" PAGETHE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/625DS.png)

Appreciate help with which content to change or add coding.

Comment: -1 and voted to close; please don't WRITE IN ALL CAPS and [please include code samples as text rather than as images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/1709587).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code.

**First** : Do not include any inline css, unless you absolutely need to give that style preference (mostly happens in case of using frameworks). Do it in a css file.

**Second** : target the id in your css using `#` symbol. like `#FooterDiv`. If you want it to be at the bottom, use `bottom:0;` not `top:300;`

**Third** : Understand the difference between `position:absolute;` and `position:fixed;`

`position:fixed;` will fix your div at the bottom and it will always be visible even if your content is scrollable.

`position:absolute;` fixes your div to the bottom of the parent that is set to `position:relative;` (in your case that is ). If your content in the parent div is scrollable then it will be visible when you scroll to the very bottom of your parent

Comment: -1 for [answering a clearly off-topic question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194989/200582) (the question is useless to future readers without an MCVE), and for characterising the use of inline CSS as a "mistake" (this is subjective, not justified here, and [a matter of debate in current front-end development discourse](https://blog.engineyard.com/2016/inline-styles-yes-or-no)).

Answer (score -1):

You overwrite the properties. In the HTML code you set a `top: 300` that overwrites the `bottom:0` from the CSS file.

Make sure you put # in front of your element in the CSS file: `#FooterDiv`

Comment: Downvoted for [answering a clearly off-topic question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/200582).

Answer (score -1):

Try adding **margin-bottom: 0px;** to your style.
Or **padding-bottom: 0px;**

Comment: -1 for [answering a clearly off-topic question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/200582), lack of clarity about which element these rules should be applied to, and lack of explanation about what effect they will have of why.